How to solve a multiple hypothesis test problem?
We ran into a problem with multiple hypothesis testing. We have a vector $x$, which is the data we observed. The components in this vector are standard normally distributed when the hypothesis $H_0$ is true. Based on the observed data vector $x$, we have constructed three chi-squared distributed test statistics $T_1$, $T_2$ and $T_3$, where $T_1=x^T(A-B)x$, $T_2=x^T(A-C)x$ and $T_3=x^T(A-D)x$. $A$, $B$ and $C$ are the semi-positive definite matrices with ranks of 6, 3 and 3, respectively. According to the properties of the chi-square distribution, the degrees of freedom of $T_1$, $T_2$ and $T_3$ are 6, 3 and 3, respectively. The four hypotheses and the conditions under which they hold are defined as follows

If $T_1<=Th_1$ or ($T_1>Th_1$ & $T_2<=Th_2$ & $T_3<=Th_3$), hypothesis $H_0$ is true;
If $T_1>Th_1$ & $T_2>Th_2$ & $T_3<=Th_3$, hypothesis $H_1$ is true;
If $T_1>Th_1$ & $T_2<=Th_2$ & $T_3>Th_3$, hypothesis $H_2$ is true;
if $T_1>Th_1$ & $T_2>Th_2$ & $T_3>Th_3$, hypothesis $H_3$ is true.

, where $H_0$ is the null hypothesis and $H_1$, $H_2$ and $H_3$ are the
alternative hypotheses. The false alarm rate (a concept in statistical signal processing theory) is defined as $Pr(H_1 \cup H_2 \cup H_3 | H_0)$, which is the probability of deciding that one of the hypotheses $H_1$ ,$H_2$ and $H_3$ is true, when the null hypothesis is the true one.
The difficulty with this problem is that the test statistics $T_1$, $T_2$ and $T_3$ are correlated, because they 'share' the term $x^TAx$. In addition, each hypothesis involves multiple test statistics.
How do we set the thresholds $Th_1$, $Th_2$ and $Th_3$ to control the false alarm rate so that it is equal the significance level α.
Thanks in Advance.

Saying that $Pr(H_1\cup H_2\cup H_3|H_0)$ is the "probability of type I error" suggests that your formal null hypotheses for the tests you are running are  $H_1, H_2, H_3$ rather than what you call $H_0$. Better call them $H_{01}, H_{02}, H_{03}$ then (in fact I'm not totally sure what you are testing). Also you are mixing up statements about the underlying unobservable truth (to which statistical hypotheses refer) and observed statiustics in the data, which makes this very confusing.

In fact, if $H_1, H_2, H_3$ are indeed statistical hypotheses, $Pr(H_1\cup H_2\cup H_3|H_0)$ can not be the probability of type I error, because statistical hypotheses are treated as fixed in testing, the data are random (i.e., "Pr" gives probabilities for them), but data apparently do not occur in this expression. Maybe you mean that $H_0$ is indeed the null hypothesis and you test it against three different alternatives (but then still your terminology confuses whether $H_1$ etc. are in fact alternative hypotheses, or a result computed on data)?

@Christian Hennig
Thank you very much for your answer! I'll explain a few of the questions you raised here. First, I confused the concept of type I error in my question, and I am sorry for not letting you clearly understand what I meant. $H_0$ is the null hypothesis, $H_1$, $H_2$, and $H_3$ are alternative hypotheses, and the vector $x$ is the data we observed, and the elements in $x$ are independent standard normally distributed only if  $H_0$ is true.

@Christian Hennig $Pr(H_1 \cup H_2 \cup H_3|H_0)$ is actually the concept of false alarm rate in statistical signal processing theory. For example, $H_0$ is true when there is only noise in the signal, and $H_1$ or $H_2$ or $H_3$ is true when there are different types of useful signals in the signal in addition to the noise. $Pr(H_1 \cup H_2 \cup H_3|H_0)$ is the probability of misjudging that there is a useful signal when there is only noise in the signal. Our goal is to make the false alarm rate constant. How should we achieve this goal in this context? We look forward to your answer!

Please give essential information in the question, not only in comments. Also note that the fact that I can see issues with the question, which hopefully contributes to clarification doesn't imply that I have a good answer to your question. By the way, I still don't understand $Pr(H_1\cup H_2\cup H_3|H_0)$, as still I don't see data there, just hypotheses.

@Christian Hennig Thank you for your suggestion, we have modified the statement in the original question. Please let me know if you are still unclear about the question.
